# jQuery Validationengine arrows not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using the validationengine with .NET so don't use the traditional class="validate[required]" on some pages as I have a few logical forms on the page and don't want the whole form validated in one go so instead use the following:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
     $j("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
         if ($j("#lstCustomerType").val() == "") {
             jQuery('#lstCustomerType').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please select a customer type', 'error', true);
     });
 });
```

The only problem I am having is that the showArrow parameter appears to do nothing.  Regardless of what I try the arrow never shows and I end up with just a popup above the textbox. On the pages that I do use class="validate[required]" the arrows show as expected.  Does anybody know if it is a limitation of the manual showing of a popup or the syntax to get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just spent all day trying to figure this one out. Here's the proper syntax for displaying those pesky arrows:

```
$('#ed').validationEngine('showPrompt', validationDate, 'error', 'topRight', true);
```

It seems that you need to provide all of the "optional" parameters or else the instantiation fails. I kept leaving out 'topRight' and the arrows would never appear. As soon as I put the position parameter in, the arrows show up.

Comment: Sullivan thanks so much for this, for some reason I had totally missed it until today and just tried your suggestion.  My validationengine notifications now look top banana!

Comment: Well, for me it works like this:

  `$('#gender').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'My Funny Error Message', 'error', '', true);`